# How to Display Shortcode's Content after Short Product Description?

Tags: shortcode

This is my Shortcode:  `[mbv name=”product-info”]`

And i want to display this shortcode's content after [WooCommerce Short Product Description](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/single-product/short-description.php#L24)

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I got a solution from below codes:**

```
add_filter('woocommerce_short_description', function ($description) {
    if (! is_product()) { return; }   
    return $description.do_shortcode('[mbv name="product-info"]');
});
```

Comment: Should probably `return $description;` on line 2, not an empty string.

Comment: @kovshenin No, Because I want to show Shortcode's content after short Description

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment, has nothing to do with your shortcode, just the fact that you're filtering the short description, and returning an empty string on all pages except `is_product()`, doesn't look intentional.

Comment: @kovshenin I use that conditional tag because i did it on my WooCommerce store's single product page, and if i didn't used that then that function also applies on /shop/ archive page.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your conditional tag, sir. I'm referring to the return statement right after it. It causes the filter to return an empty string for the short description, everywhere, except your single product page. As I mentioned, I believe this was unintentional, but who am I to know :D Best of luck, sir.

Comment: @kovshenin My English is not good that's why i am not understanding anything frequently,  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

add this line:

```
echo do_shortcode('[mbv name=”product-info”]');
```

Comment: That's half the problem, but I think OP would also want to know where to put that specifically. (Which is probably going to be in a filter somewhere if this is in one of the WooCommerce templates.)